# How to access fetched data and visualize it using template literals

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, template-literals

I'm fetching some json data and:

I get some of the data diplayed here:
[image];

so far I've manage to display everything on the frontend, but I can not access it:
ex: [image: empty node list]
here is the data visualized: ex:[image: data has populated the html elements]

As I'm also using template literals, but every time I've tried to refer to the element within the template using querySelectorAll, I get a nodeList with nothing inside, however the element are there.

I'm trying to make it so that when you push a button within an area, will display the fetched data of only that area, and then you can update the data, that's the final goal,

ld be the best method to use to being able to get the element that gets created using template literals and then specifying that I need to see only the data that correspond to that clicked button?

I know is a lot of things.

here is my JS:

```
// to fetch data from backend.
// const link = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
const link = './data copy.json';

// const container = document.getElementById('.item-container');
fetch(link)
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
console.log(data);

        data.forEach( gun => {
            const template = `
    <div class="ticket">
    <div class="id card"><p>${gun.gunId}</p>
  </div>
    <div class="location card">
      <p class="gun-id">${gun.location}</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="description card">
      <button class="view" id="${gun.gunId}"onclick="modalForm(),updateForm(this.id)">Details</button>
      <div  class="modal">
      <form class="modal-content" id ="form-data"onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm();">
        <div class="form-header">
          <h1 id="" class="gun-form-name"></h1>
          <span id="" class="close" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
          <span id="" class="back-arrow fa-lg" type="button" onclick="goBack()" role="button" aria-label="Go Back Button"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
           </span></div>
        <section class="main-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <h3 id="title-id">${gun.gunId}</h3>
                    <div class="img">
                        <img class="gun-image"src="gun image.PNG" alt="test">
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-1" type="button">${gun.partId.lightPipeId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-2" type="button">${gun.partId.lightbugId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-3" type="button">${gun.partId.batteryId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-4" type="button">${gun.partId.triggerId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-5" type="button">${gun.partId.triggerPcb}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-6" type="button">${gun.partId.triggerSpring}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-7" type="button">${gun.partId.grayCable}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-8" type="button">${gun.partId.powerCableid}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-9" type="button">${gun.partId.stockPcb}</button>
        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="details">
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p>
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p> 
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p> 
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p> 
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button class="close-ticket"type="button">Close Ticket</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        
      </form>
    </div>
  
    </div>
  <div class="close-bt card">
    <button class="delete-button"id="${gun.gunId}">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>`  
            document.getElementById('item-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
        });
        document.getElementById('open-tickets').innerHTML=data.length;
      })
    .catch(error=> console.log(error));

const modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
console.log(modal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember `fetch()` is asynchronous, so while all the code in your `.then()` callback blocks will execute after the initial fetch call resolves, your `querySelectorAll` sits outside that promise chain.

Look at it like this:

```
fetch(link)
    .then((res) => { //...
    })
    .then((data) => { //...
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

const modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
console.log(modal);
```

When your `fetch()` call is made and an unresolved promise is returned, `const modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');` is immediately ran as it is not within the promise chain. At this point, your template literal HTML has not been inserted into the DOM.

To fix this, you need to incorporate the statement as a dependent of the JSON parse promise:

```
fetch(link)
    .then((res) => { //...
    })
    .then((data) => { //...
        const modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        console.log(modal);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Thanks @damonholder for the answer, now I can access the html elements, can I also ask, what would it be the best way to run a function for each element of the returned nodelist? so for example, if a I click button 1 I want only to see the childnote 1?

Comment: Non focussed questions and expanding on a question in a comment is bad practice here. If you have a separate question ask it in a separate post. If you want to be more specific in this question, then modify the question and I will modify my answer accordingly.